# ElasticsearchRepository - Modify the @Query value

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

Currently I'm working with a ElasticsearchRepository and Springboot Data. I can write a simple method with a simple Query annotation:

```
@Query("{\"bool\":{\"must\":[{\"match\":{\"_resource\":\"?0\"}}]}}")
List<Activity> findByResource(String resource);
```

However, the Activity index might have different, multiple fields (varying from line to line in logstash). So, I might need to add multiple match clauses. I was testing adding a second parameter that would contain the rest of the params (if any) like this:

```
@Query("{\"bool\":{\"must\":[{\"match\":{\"_resource\":\"?0\"}}?1]}}")
List<Activity> findByResource(String resource, String additionalClauses);
```

the second parameter could look like this:

```
String additional = ",{\"match\":{\"_method\":\"GET\"}}
```

However, I get this exception when calling the endpoint with the service:

```
Elasticsearch exception [type=x_content_parse_exception, reason=[1:60] [bool] failed to parse field [must]]; nested exception is ElasticsearchStatusException[Elasticsearch exception [type=x_content_parse_exception, reason=[1:60] [bool] failed to parse field [must]]]; nested: ElasticsearchException[Elasticsearch exception [type=json_parse_exception, reason=Unexpected character ('\\' (code 92)): was expecting double-quote to start field name\n at [Source: (ByteArrayInputStream); line: 1, column: 62]]];
```

I understand that what I was trying to do isn't not the ideal way to use the @Query annotation (I don't think it's even allowed to do what I'm trying), so:

- Is there a different way to accomplish this?
- Is @Query que only option I have? How could I do it then?

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing additional query components as parameter in this way is not possible. If a parameter is a String it will be quoted and escaped before being inserted into the value of the `@Query` annotation. This created String is then used to build a `StringQuery`.

You will need to create one of the `Query` variants (see https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/4.3.0/reference/html/#elasticsearch.operations.queries for details), probably a `StringQuery` and pass that to the `ElasticsearchOperations`.

Comment: Yeah, I had to rely on the ElasticsearchOperations interface. I wanted to handle everything on the ElasticsearchRepository interface, but I guess not everything is possible. Thanks!

Comment: You can still do that by writing a repository extension (see https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/4.3.0/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations for the principle and https://www.sothawo.com/2020/09/search-entities-within-a-geographic-distance-with-spring-data-elasticsearch-4/ for an example how this is done)

Comment: That sound neat. I'll give a try with a different service and see how it goes. The more the merrier.